# Can't connect to the remote computer, remote desktop 2008 r2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop-services

Before all, sorry by my english.

Well thats the situation, i have installed a Windows Server 2008 R2 with Remote Desktop services for accessing outside. What it's happening is that when i try to stablish connection from client computer, every things appears to go fine, except that if i have not open a local session with the same user, i get the error "Remote Desktop can't connect to the remote computer..."... but if i had previously open session with that user locally on server, the remote conection is opened perfectly...

Any idea???

Answer (score 1):

Did you go through the steps necessary to enable remote desktop on the windows 2008R2 system? I'd follow the directions here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794832(v=ws.10).aspx

accounts and group memberships at Local and Domain Default Groups (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=83477).

excerpt from the above URL:

> To enable Remote Desktop locally by using Server Manager Open Server
>   Manager.
>
> To open Server Manager, click Start, point to Administrative
>   Tools, and then click Server Manager.
>
> In Computer Information, click Configure Remote Desktop.
>
> In the System Properties dialog box, under Remote Desktop, click one
>   of the following options:
>
> Allow connections from computers running any version of Remote Desktop
>   (less secure). Use this option if you do not know the version of
>   Remote Desktop Connection that will be used to connect to this server.
>
> Allow connections only from computers running Remote Desktop with
>   Network Level Authentication (more secure). Use this option if you
>   know that the users who will connect to this server are running
>   Windows Vista or Windows Server 2008.
>
> Review the information in the Remote Desktop dialog box, and then
>   click OK twice.

There are more thorough instructions here : http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_Windows_Server_2008_Remote_Desktop_Administration.

Comment: Yes. I have included the right users and/or groups into the "Remote Desktop Users".

   I have included the group  "Remote Desktop Users" into the policy "allow start session through remote desktop services".

Comment: I have the same configuration in another server and works perfectly, but in this one, i dont know why exactly i'm having this issue. The most rare thing is what i explained before, trying to establish a remote desktop session with aministrator user, for example, if i had a local session opened with that user (Admin), i can open remote desktop session with no problems, the local session is finished and the remote one is opened without probles, but if i have no sessions opened in the server locally, i get the error... why???????

Comment: Firewall rule open to allow RDP traffic in? This would be the firewall on the 2008R2 box.

Comment: Firewall is disabled :(